# how to win the lotto

Tags: probability, random

Firstly let me be clear, I don't play the lottery or even follow draws, but something going round in my head for some time are the possible results of a lottery draw.

The chance in a $6/49$ lottery is roughly $1$ in $13,983,816$ but that is also a big odds against any pattern to emerge, for instance, its very unlikely that $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ will ever occur, for that matter so would $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$ or even $\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11\}$.

This brings me to my question, is there a way to describe all possible "ordered" results and subtract that from the total odds?
[Wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_mathematics)

Comment: The result (1 2 3 4 5 6) is as probable as any other.

Comment: What do you mean by ordered results?

Comment: Are you asking about the number of possible rising sequences with 6 items? If so then any unique sequence can be arranged in a rising manner. Or does the order they actually appear matter? Then out of all the ways to get some 6 numbers (6!) only one is a rising sequence therefore 1/6! of the total results are rising.

Comment: I struggle to accept that that an ordered sequence of numbers like 123456 has as much chance to occur as a random group, it feels wrong

Comment: For an object to be random it doesn't need to have no structure.

Comment: @peterretief Play lotto with two balls instead of six. Does it still feel wrong? Play lotto with a total of four numbers from which you draw three.

Comment: Why don't you throw a set of three dice a sufficiently large number of times to convince yourself that the sequence (1 2 3) is just as likely as, say, (5 1 4).

Comment: so if I have a basket of red balls and blue balls if i mix them they will eventually become ordered again?

Comment: @peterretief: The longer you mix them up the greater the probability that they eventually become ordered again.

Comment: I do not believe the user is asking whether 1 2 3 4 5 6 is less likely than a given random string; I believe (s)he is asking for a measure of randomness (something along the lines of Shannon entropy perhaps) of a string, and to calculate the probability of a given random (!) string having a measure greater than some fixed randomness, according to that measure.

Comment: @JasonPolak thanks that's a great answer in fact its the question I was trying to ask

Comment: http://planetmath.org/ShannonsTheoremEntropy.html @JasonPolak If you answer I will mark it as my question answered

Comment: @JasonPolak I don't think so. It seems to me that he is thinking that some particular sequences ("ordered", those that look "not random" for him) are less probable than others, and that by betting outside that special set he will have more chance of winning. That's fundamentally wrong, and that set is not special.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One should not be mislead in considering properties of numbers to derive "likeness" of particular lottery draws. Lotteries use numbers simply as a concrete device to make balls distinguishable and bets easy to make.

Were the lotteries use abstract symbols such as
$$
\bullet\qquad\times\qquad\oplus\qquad\circ\qquad\ddagger\qquad\nabla\qquad...
$$
to diversify the balls, all the numerical "coincidences" would just disappear proving what they really are: psychologically induced illusions.

Comment: I did mention coloured balls, but I get what you are saying, but say we had 49 shades of green added from light to dark in a container, the container gets mixed and I "know" that it will never be randomly restored to its origional state, the word entropy was mentioned